# Script fetches the same results from first page even after clicking on the next button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to scrape the content populated upon initiating a serach in the search box in google map. My script can generate results by pressing that search button. Now I wish to keep parsing the results by pressing the next button (located at the bottom left) until there is none.

[Site address](https://www.google.com/maps/search/)

I'm using this `motels in new jersey` keyword as search.

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/search/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#searchboxinput"))).send_keys("motels in new jersey")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#searchbox-searchbutton"))).click()

while True:
    for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-result-content"))):
        name = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3[class='section-result-title'] > span"))).text
        print(name)

    try:
        next_page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[jsaction$='.nextPage'] > span")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",next_page)
    except TimeoutException: break

driver.quit()
```

The above script gives me the same results (from first page) several times no matter how far it goes clicking on that ***next button***.

***How can I get the accurate results from next pages?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic that should work.

There is a server error (application issue) occurring when navigating through the list, so are waiting for the page to load the information and then check if server error displayed, if not then continue with population of the results.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/search/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#searchboxinput"))).send_keys("motels in new jersey")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#searchbox-searchbutton"))).click()

while True:
    # wait until the information is loaded
    wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='searchbox'][contains(@class,'loading')]")))
    # check if there is any server error
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='snackbar-message'][contains(.,'error')]"))>0:
        # print the error message
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='snackbar-message'][contains(.,'error')]").text)
        # exit the loop
        break


    for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-result-content"))):
        name = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3[class='section-result-title'] > span"))).text
        print(name)

    try:
        next_page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[jsaction$='.nextPage'] > span")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",next_page)
    except TimeoutException: break
```

Comment: What an elegant fix @supputuri. I kept trying with `wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#searchbox a.gsst_a > span")))` but no luck. It seems, I was going after the wrong selector.

Answer (score 0):

Being in a `while True` loop, your script does not wait for the next page to be rendered before searching for the name. The locators `input#searchboxinput` and `button#searchbox-searchbutton` are still active when the next page is loading. Thus your script will output the same names from the same page for as many iterations as will run before the next page is loaded.

I recommend a wait condition for the page loading, such as the presence of the spinner animation in the top left where the X button usually is. This should pause the execution until the next page is loaded. The div with id `searchbox` has a `show-loading` class appear only while that spinner is active. You can use that to determine if the page is still loading.

Comment: I'm not after any theoretical solution as you can see I've already provided the full script @Enioluwa Segun. Thanks for your suggestion.